# How can I remove a password on an Excel 2007 VBA project?

Tags: passwords, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Is there any way to remove the password on an Excel 2007 VBA project? (Either within Excel itself of with some other application.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can open the project and save it, this looks like it might work:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP051988581033.aspx

If you can't open the project, and you have to crack the password, that's tougher. Looks like Microsoft beefed up the encryption in Office 2007 a *lot* over previous versions of Office, so this is a tall order.

I think you'll be best off with a paid product unless you want to visit the risky, seamy underbelly of the internet.

http://www.lostpassword.com/excel.htm

That looks viable..