# Freeware tool to crack excel password

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, passwords, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Remove password from an Excel Document](https://superuser.com/questions/58263/remove-password-from-an-excel-document)

I have an Excel document that is password protected

Are there any freeware tools out there to crack the password to open a document? I've seen a lot of commercial tools available, but no freeware ones.

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/96644/remove-password-on-excel-2007

Comment: This has nothing to do with VBA. I only need to crack the password to open the file, not to edit the VBA code

Comment: He does ask for a freeware version, the other doesn't. However, I fear the answer is going to be: there isn't any and then this question doesn't add anything new

Comment: Maybe not now, but a solution may be found months later, like http://superuser.com/questions/4614/

Comment: Just for the record, voting to reopen.  Though "freeware tools" are a subset of "tools", it's a very significant segment for those looking to do things on the cheap (students, IT depts w/ no budget, cheap people), and not likely to be answered well in for-pay questions.

Comment: @hyperslug - nothing prevents someone from posting a freeware solution in the other topic, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two places you can try to get the Macros to crack protected Excel workbooks:

[How to remove, crack, or break a forgotten Excel xls password](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-remove-crack-or-break-a-forgotten-excel-xls-password/)

[AllInternalPasswords](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/removepwords.html)

I've had successes and failures with both.  It's mostly just trial and error at this point.

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice. It works for write-protection, at least (I last tried with version 2.4, and it may be a bug). Just turn off write protection, and it won't ask for a password.

If you want to crack read protection, then I don't know if it works. And if you want to read protect your documents, encrypt it instead of simply password protecting it with MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for years and it's never let me down.(worrying really) :-)
http://www.straxx.com/excel/password.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such a tool that brute-forced the password, against a file that I owned BTW. I'll be happy to share it, when I find the source. It worked for me :)